# Kendo UI Web - Selected item in DropDownList showing as 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm using a Kendo UI grid in my application. A DropDownList has been used in the Category column editor to assign Categories to Products. A Category has a one-to-one foreign key relationship with a Product. I've set up [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/UQIfIhuke/2/) to illustrate what I mean.

Let's say I have assigned the category 'Beverages' in the DropDownList to a product called 'Chai'. When I try to add a new product or update 'Chai', Beverages shows up in the DropDownList as 'undefined'. Any idea why?

**Edit:**
The snippet I've posted uses OData and fetches data from Telerik's Northwind sample. I'm using WebAPI in my own application.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Could you perhaps rephrase it? Where is your Dropdownlist, what and where is item #2? Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've edited my question to clarify. Please refer to the JSBin if in doubt.

Comment: When I try to edit/update 'Chai', I click on 'Edit' and then select say 'Condiments', it changes in the Category column but when I click u'pdate' nothing happens. So I can't really test update or even add

Comment: nothing happens because the update operation is not implemented in the datasource.

Comment: Telerik's sample using OData doesn't allow update, that's the problem. In my own model, update works fine and foreign key IDs are reflected correctly in the database. Just doesn't display correctly in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

The code for custom editor looks good, it might be just the case of your JsBin but, I don't see implementation of the `update` in the data source transport ?

Assuming that above is not the case, sometimes you need to remap the dropdown model to the grid model, implement `save` event on the grid to do so:

```
  save: function (e) {
          e.model.yourproperty= yourdropdowninstance.text();
         }
```

Adding debugger into the above event will help you to understand what's going on after you hit update button, see ig the value is passed from ddl to the grid model.